# how do I synchronize threads in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, locking

It appears that VC++ 2010 does not support mutex. I have a function as follows.

```
DWORD WINAPI WatchItThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
{


    int *t=static_cast<int*>(lpParam);  
    while (true)
    {
        short cpuUsage = usage.GetUsage(DWORD(*t));

        printf("Thread id %d: %d%% cpu usage\n", *t, cpuUsage);
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

In the main function I create two threads as follows.

```
DWORD    i1=2632;
DWORD    i2=4040;

void *p1=&i1;
void *p2=&i2;


CreateThread(NULL, 0, WatchItThreadProc, p1, 0, NULL);
CreateThread(NULL, 0, WatchItThreadProc, p2, 0, NULL);
```

I need to synchronize these two threads in order to avoid race conditions. How do i achieve it with Visual C++ 2010?

Comment: What makes you think 2010 does not support mutexes? See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Mutex is supported. 
Refer:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx

All you need to do is CreateMutex(), WaitForSingleObject() and later ReleaseMutex() to synchronize your two threads. You might have forgot link to Kernel32 library.